# XSLT grouping child nodes for each sibling

Tags: xslt, grouping, parent-child, siblings

I have been working with XSLT lately, but now I got to a new problem trying to group a new xml file. I can't work out how to put a scope on the grouping. I want to group the `<Detail>` inside every `<Info>` node. Simple sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Info>
    <Id>1111</Id>
  <Detail type="A" group="1" >
    <Data>
      <Nr>1</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>2</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>3</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>4</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="2">
    <Data>
      <Nr>5</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="A" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>6</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
 </Info>
 <Info>
   <Id>2222</Id>
    <Detail type="A" group="1" >
      <Data>
        <Nr>1</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
    <Detail type="B" group="1">
      <Data>
        <Nr>2</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
    <Detail type="A" group="1">
      <Data>
        <Nr>3</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
  </Info>
</File>
```

The output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Info>
    <Id>1111</Id>
  <Detail type="A" group="1" >
    <Data>
      <Nr>1</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>2</Nr>
    </Data>
      <Data>
      <Nr>6</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>3</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>4</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="2">
    <Data>
      <Nr>5</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
 </Info>
 <Info>
   <Id>2222</Id>
    <Detail type="A" group="1" >
      <Data>
        <Nr>1</Nr>
      </Data>
          <Data>
        <Nr>3</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
    <Detail type="B" group="1">
      <Data>
        <Nr>2</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
  </Info>
</File>
```

In my try I don't know how to copy the values from the `<Info>` element (ID, it could be other elements too), I just write out `<Info>` element, and every `<Detail>` gets grouped in the first `<Info>` element, leaving the last `<Info>` element empty.

Here is my xslt so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="details" match="Detail"
          use="concat(@type,'_',@group)"/>
  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <File>
      <xsl:for-each select="File/Info">
        <Info>
        <xsl:for-each select="Detail[count(. | key('details', concat(@type,'_',@group))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="concat(@type,'_',@group)" />
        <Detail type="{@type}" group="{@group}">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('details', concat(@type,'_',@group))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Data"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Detail>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Info>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </File>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is my result so far

```
<File>
  <Info>
    <Detail type="A" group="1">
      <Data>
        <Nr>1</Nr>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Nr>2</Nr>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Nr>6</Nr>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Nr>1</Nr>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Nr>3</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
    <Detail type="B" group="1">
      <Data>
        <Nr>3</Nr>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Nr>4</Nr>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Nr>2</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
    <Detail type="B" group="2">
      <Data>
        <Nr>5</Nr>
      </Data>
    </Detail>
  </Info>
  <Info />
</File>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDetailChildren" match="Detail"
  use="concat(generate-id(..),'+',@type,'+',@group)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "Detail
   [not(generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kDetailChildren',
                        concat(generate-id(..),'+',@type,'+',@group)
                        )[1])
        )]"/>
 <xsl:template match="Detail">
  <Detail>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "key('kDetailChildren',
         concat(generate-id(..),'+',@type,'+',@group)
         )/node()"/>
  </Detail>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<File>
    <Info>
        <Id>1111</Id>
        <Detail type="A" group="1" >
            <Data>
                <Nr>1</Nr>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Nr>2</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
        <Detail type="B" group="1">
            <Data>
                <Nr>3</Nr>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <Nr>4</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
        <Detail type="B" group="2">
            <Data>
                <Nr>5</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
        <Detail type="A" group="1">
            <Data>
                <Nr>6</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
    </Info>
    <Info>
        <Id>2222</Id>
        <Detail type="A" group="1" >
            <Data>
                <Nr>1</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
        <Detail type="B" group="1">
            <Data>
                <Nr>2</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
        <Detail type="A" group="1">
            <Data>
                <Nr>3</Nr>
            </Data>
        </Detail>
    </Info>
</File>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<File>
   <Info>
      <Id>1111</Id>
      <Detail type="A" group="1">
         <Data>
            <Nr>1</Nr>
         </Data>
         <Data>
            <Nr>2</Nr>
         </Data>
         <Data>
            <Nr>6</Nr>
         </Data>
      </Detail>
      <Detail type="B" group="1">
         <Data>
            <Nr>3</Nr>
         </Data>
         <Data>
            <Nr>4</Nr>
         </Data>
      </Detail>
      <Detail type="B" group="2">
         <Data>
            <Nr>5</Nr>
         </Data>
      </Detail>
   </Info>
   <Info>
      <Id>2222</Id>
      <Detail type="A" group="1">
         <Data>
            <Nr>1</Nr>
         </Data>
         <Data>
            <Nr>3</Nr>
         </Data>
      </Detail>
      <Detail type="B" group="1">
         <Data>
            <Nr>2</Nr>
         </Data>
      </Detail>
   </Info>
</File>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of the *identity rule* and the *Muenchian* grouping method using composite keys.
2. Note how the parent's identity is included in the key.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer, it worked fine to reuse in the real format. I'll now use some time to understand the flow.